# Magento 2 Category rule and override the cart file by plugin

Tags: magento2, php, admin, magento2.4, plugin

how do I can set up a rule in Magento 2 by category, If need to do something like this:
I one product that is from one category is added to the cart then the customer can't add any product from another category in the cart?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to register your module with **registration.php**. The file location will be

> app/code/Softi/CartProduct/registration.php

```
<?php

 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
 'Softi_CartProduct',
  __DIR__
 );
```

Create **module.xml** file. In this file, you will define your module name and version. The file location will be

> app/code/Softi/CartProduct/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
     <module name="Softi_CartProduct" schema_version="0.0.1" setup_version="0.0.1"/>
 </config>
```

Create a **di.xml** file to override the cart class. The file location will be

> app/code/Softi/CartProduct/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart">
    <plugin name="interceptAddingProductToCart"
            type="Softi\CartProduct\Plugin\CartPlugin"
            sortOrder="10"
            disabled="false"/>
    </type>
 </config>
```

now create **CartPlugin.php** in the following path.

> app/code/Softi/CartProduct/Plugin/CartPlugin.php

```
<?php

  namespace Softi\CartProduct\Plugin;

   class CartPlugin
 {



public function __construct(
  
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductCategoryList $productCategory,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\CollectionFactory $itemCollection,
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart

) {
    $this->itemCollection = $itemCollection;
    $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    $this->productCategory = $productCategory;
    $this->cart = $cart;



}

public function beforeAddProduct($subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo = null)
{

    $productcatId = $productInfo->getId();

    $categoryIds = $this->productCategory->getCategoryIds($productcatId);
    $category = [];
    if ($categoryIds) {
        $category = array_unique($categoryIds);
    }

    $items = $this->cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
    if($items) {

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $categoryId = $this->productCategory->getCategoryIds($item->getProductId());
            $CartProductcategory = [];

              if ($categoryId) {
                   $CartProductcategory = array_unique($categoryId);
               }
           }
       
           if( $category === $CartProductcategory){
                return [$productInfo, $requestInfo];
            } else {
                messageManager->addError(__('add same category product'));
            }

        } else {
            return [$productInfo, $requestInfo];
     }
  }
}
```

Run the following command:

sudo bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo bin/magento cache:flush

here vendor_name = '**Softi**' and module_name = '**CartProduct**'
you can change it according to your requirment.

I hope it would be helpful for you.

Comment: Hi, thank you, I'm not so good on modules, can you tell me where I can add the categories ID or product ID?

Comment: I didn't understand your words.
are you want to add your code in the core file?

Comment: no, I think will be fine to create a new module, but how I can setup the rule?

Comment: cleck the following link to learn to make the module.
https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-create-helloworld-module/

however, if you don't understand then tell me I will edit the code completely.

Comment: yes will help me a lot if you can help me with that module ... thank you

Comment: I edited my previous code now check it.
I think you will understand it clearly and will be no need to help more.

Comment: Hi, thank you, can you explain me please how this module work or what do exactly?

Comment: when a customer adds a product to the cart then he is not able to add another product from another category, he could only add the product from that category that he is already added to the cart.